# Windows Server 2008 Antivirus Software with an API

Tags: api, windows-server-2008, antivirus

I'm looking for an Antivirus package that is compliant with Windows Server 2008. That's not the hard part. What I need is an API layer on the Antivirus that i can call from managed .net code.

For example: I am developing an Asp.Net (C#) website that allows users to upload files to the web server which the web site resides on. We have full control of the server so there are no security/rights issues on the server. I need to be able to run the antivirus algorithm on the newly uploaded files without (hopefully) shelling out to a command-ilne version of the software.

Does anyone know of such a package?

Comment: This normally already happens automatically with any server-class antivirus product. No need to write special code for it.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: True, but it would be faster if it didn't scan every file automatically and only scanned the ones you explicitly requested it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Symantec Scan engine (http://www.symantec.com/business/scan-engine) with some success calling from Java. It has an TCP/IP based API so it should be possible to use it with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

If files are saved on the server, most anti-virus suits will scan them immediately, and delete/quarantine the infected files. In that regard, by the time you run the command-line tool they were already scanned.

Comment: Exactly. What I'm trying to avoid however is allowing the anti-virus suite that much control. I want to micro-manage the software via an API to only scan what I want, when I want as I host multiple websites from the same web server as well as being the website/server administrator rolled into one I know what needs to be scanned and what is a waste of server resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at MetaScan (Google it) it will hook into and provide an API for most virus scan packages. We use it to provide virus scan in our software package if the client has a virus software policy in place.